# PowerBI dynamic filter for period

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would need a report that shows variances for the current period, next period, half-year and year-end.
There is a period filter from 1 to 12 representing the periods in a year.

I can build up a table that shows the difference:

- for the current period (can be amended based on the period filter)
- for full-year (using ALL function to ignore the period filter)

But I don't know how to write a dax that filter just for the first 6 periods as half-year.

Or add one to the current period filter to shows the next period-related variance.
Also, that should be dynamic. This means if I adjust the period filter it should show always be the next period. (If the filter is set for 1 to 4 it returns 1 to 5; set 2 to 7 returns 2 to 8).

Could you please help me with how to do that?

Thanks

So, let's say we have 2 databases.
The plan for the current year and the actuals:

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjMvQ.png)

And I would like to see the difference between them in one visualization.
If the period set is 1 to 2:

for the current period shows: sum plan (1-2) - sum Actual (1-2)
next period: sum plan (1-3) - sum Actual (1-3)
Half Year: sum plan (H1) - sum Actual (H1)
FY: sum plan (1-12) - sum Actual (1-12)

Comment: Add your sample data and desired output for certain filter condition

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand exact query but it seems that as per your given examples it's more related to time intelligence formulas in PowerBi to given results based on specific time frames. (YTD, QTD etc)

Below is the link to address your query via time intelligence formula

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/time-intelligence-power-bi/